# Bitbake fetch layers from github repo

Tags: inheritance, layer, yocto, bitbake

I want to extend my Yocto SDK with Qt5. For this I rely on:
https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5

Can I add a recipe to fetch that repository, include those layers to the build and inherit from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as well I know recipes aren't designed by Yocto team to fetch whole meta layer. Even that after sourcing script *oe-init-build-env* to setup build workspace You need to add path to layer in *conf/bblayers.conf* file. So I think that You approach is not good idea :).

For setup Your workspace consider use some tool or do it manually (I can proposal You to use repo tool - https://source.android.com/source/using-repo)